# Verificar input senha

Tags: javascript, html, validação, input

Olá, estou começando a aprender JavaScript e não estou conseguindo de nenhuma forma fazer meu código validar se existem 3 caracteres em maiúsculo, 2 números e 1 caractere especial no meu input. Gostaria de saber o que devo estar fazendo de erro, pois fiz diversas tentativas, pesquisei em diversos sites e nenhuma forma funciona. Segue o código base:

```
            /* Validação do Campo Senha*/
        if (document.formulario.senha.value.length < 8) {
           alert("A senha deve conter no minímo 8 digitos!");
           document.formulario.senha.focus();
           return false;
       }
```

Obrigada pela atenção!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Larissa**, use REGEX:

```
var senha = document.formulario.senha;
var regex = /^(?=(?:.*?[A-Z]){3})(?=(?:.*?[0-9]){2})(?=(?:.*?[!@#$%*()_+^&}{:;?.]){1})(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%;*(){}_+^&]*$/; 

if(senha.length < 8)
{
    alert("A senha deve conter no minímo 8 digitos!");
    document.formulario.senha.focus();
    return false;
}
else if(!regex.exec(senha))
{
    alert("A senha deve conter no mínimo 3 caracteres em maiúsculo, 2 números e 1 caractere especial!");
    document.formulario.senha.focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Explicando regex:

```
// (?=(?:.*?[A-Z]){3}) - Mínimo 3 letras maiúsculas
// (?=(?:.*?[0-9]){2}) - Mínimo 2 números
// (?=(?:.*?[!@#$%*()_+^&}{:;?.]){1})(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#;$%*(){}_+^&] - Mínimo 1 caractere especial
```

Comment: O código funcionou mais infelizmente a única informação que apresenta é a do "else if".

Comment: Excelente @Felipe, bem mais prático

Comment: Imagina @MaiconCarraro! O seu verifica mais caracteres especiais.

Comment: @LarissaMourullo, não entendi, como assim a única informação é a do `else if`?

Answer (score 0):

Talvez não seja o melhor jeito, mas está bem didático. Se quiser saber sobre os valores `ASCII` que utilizei no código dê uma olhada aqui: http://www.asciitable.com/

```js
function valido() {
  var senha = document.formulario.senha.value;
  
  var letraMaiscula = 0;
  var numero = 0;
  var caracterEspecial = 0;
  var caracteresEspeciais = "/([~`!@#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\":<>\?])"; // adicione o que quiser pra validar como caracter especial
  
  for (var i=0; i <= senha.length; i++) {
    var valorAscii = senha.charCodeAt(i);
    
    // de A até Z
    if (valorAscii >= 65 && valorAscii <= 90)
      letraMaiscula++;
    
    // de 0 até 9
    if (valorAscii >= 48 && valorAscii <= 57)
      numero++;
    
    // indexOf retorna -1 quando NÃO encontra
    if (caracteresEspeciais.indexOf(senha[i]) != -1)
      caracterEspecial++;
  }
        
  return (letraMaiscula >= 3) && (numero >= 2) && (caracterEspecial >= 1);
}
```

```html
<form name="formulario">
  <input name="senha" />
  
  <input type="submit" onclick="return valido()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: O código não chegou nem a funcionar infelizmente.

Comment: @LarissaMourullo E o que aconteceu?