# Fazer verificação em string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

No evento `keyup` de um `input` quero verificar os seguintes casos:

- Se `string` tem letra e número `"abc123"`;
- Se `string` tem letras maiúsculas e minúsculas `"aBc"`;
- Se `string` tem caracter não alfa numérico `"a#B1 c"`;

Como posso fazer para olhar se a `string` tem esses `caracteres`?

Comment: Você quer só saber se tem, ou quer fazer alguma coisa com os dados se tiver? Está um pouco vaga a pergunta.

Comment: Apenas se tem, daí dependendo se tiver ou não vou fazer ações em outros objetos, mas não nesses dados.

Comment: Entendi. Aqui talvez já tenha algo que ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+regex .Lembro de ter visto alguma coisa boa sem RegEx também, para validar senhas, já pronta no site. Se eu achar aviso. **Lembrando que**, se for para usar os dados em algum sistema server-side, tem que checar do lado do servidor também.

Comment: Algumas coisas parecidas, veja se alguma serve: [Montar RegEx para validar senha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93883/) e [Verificar input senha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71709/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz uma versão que verifica paulatinamente o que você especificou na pergunta.

```js
    $('#test').keyup(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      var letras,
          numeros,
          letrasMaiusculas,
          especial;

      if(/[a-z]/gm.test(value)){
        letras = " Letras minúsculas";
      }else{
        letras = "";
      }
      if(/[0-9]/gm.test(value)){
        numeros = " Números ";
      }else{
        numeros = "";
      }
      if(/[A-Z]/gm.test(value)){
        letrasMaiusculas = " letras maiúsculas ";
      }else{
        letrasMaiusculas = "";
      }
      if(/[!@#$%*()_+^&{}}:;?.]/gm.test(value)){
        especial = " Caracteres especiais não alfaNuméricos ";
      }else{
        especial = "";
      }

      $('p').html("O string possui: " + letras + "|" + numeros + "|" + letrasMaiusculas + "|" + especial)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test">
<br>
<p></p>
```

Mas é importante que fique sabido que a senha ainda possui mais algumas especificações, fiz apenas o que tinha na pergunta, mas para um modelo completo imagino que um dos exemplos do Bacco lhe sirva.

Comment: OBRIGADA por dar um exemplo funcionando...  assim a gente consegue estudar! e ENTENDER!

Answer (score 2):

**Exemplo:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://xregexp.com/v/3.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var regex = XRegExp('([\\p{Lu}]+[\\p{Ll}]+|[\\p{Ll}]+[\\p{Lu}]+)|[0-9]+[\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}]+|[\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}]+[0-9]+|([^\\p{L}0-9])+');

        console.log("Ola1: "+regex.test("Ola1"));
        console.log("olá: "+regex.test("olá"));

    </script>
    <title>Hey</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Resultado: (ver consola)**

```
Ola1: true
olá: false
```

**Explicação:**

**Passo 1:** Incluir este script (http://xregexp.com/v/3.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js) no html

```
<script src="http://xregexp.com/v/3.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```

**Passo 2:** Declarar o regex a utilizar

```
var regex = XRegExp('([\\p{Lu}]+[\\p{Ll}]+|[\\p{Ll}]+[\\p{Lu}]+)|[0-9]+[\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}]+|[\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}]+[0-9]+|([^\\p{L}0-9])+');
```

**Passo 3:** Utilizar

```
var resultado = regex.test("string a testar");
```

Se a variável resultado for true então a string tem algum dos casos. Caso contrário, não tem.

Apenas é necessário o script externo porque regex em javascript não consegue reconhecer letras não inglesas (á, Á, ç, é, í, etc.)

Se não for preciso reconhecer estas letras basta usar:

```
var regex = /(([a-z]+[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+[a-z]+)|([0-9]+[A-Za-z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+[0-9])+|([\W]))/;
var resultado = regex.test("string a testar");
```