# Checar se uma string é um número e checar se é carácter especial

Tags: javascript

Olá,estou aprendendo os comandos de condição de JavaScript e estou fazendo um exercício,o objetivo do programa é: *O usuário digita uma letra, o programa checa se a letra é uma vogal ou uma consoante*,então fiz esse código:

```
var letra = prompt("Digite uma letra:");

//passando variável para minúscula 
letra = letra.toLowerCase();

//checando vogais

if(letra == "a" || letra == "e" || letra == "i" ||       letra == "o" || letra == "u"){
    document.write(letra + " é uma vogal");
}
else{
    document.write(letra + " é uma consoante!");
}
```

Só que encontrei dois problemas

1.Checar se é número

Por exemplo, se o usuário digitar:
4 o resultado é: **4 é uma consoante!**

Para o programa 4 não é vogal, logo é consoante,então eu **quero checar se a string é um ‘número’** e imprimir para o usuário que é para digitar apenas letras

2.Checar se são outros carácteres ex;#%*

Por exemplo, se o usuário digitar: #
o resultado é: **# é uma consoante**

Logo, **quero checar se a string é um carácter especial** e se for, imprimir para ele digitar apenas letras

*Quero criar dois else if no programa para checar se a string é um número e se a string é um carácter especial

*Estou aprendendo JavaScript e é um exercício com if/else então se possível quero uma solução com JavaScript puro(Sem Jquery se possível)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Fazer verificação em string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105851/fazer-verifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) fica tudo mais fácil, para resolver seu problema desenvolvi um `while` que testa se o `input` fornecido é um caractere especial ou número, enquanto for ele continua pedindo uma letra, até que o usuário insira a letra e o loop seja quebrado. Qualquer duvida estou a disposição... dica, o Regexp é bastante importante para facilitar validação, não esqueça de dedicar tempo a ele.

```js
var regexVogal = /[aeiou]/i; //Regex para capturar vogais
var regexEspecialCharacters = /(\W)|(\d)/i; //Regex para detectar caracteres especials
var letra = prompt("Digite uma letra:");

//Enquanto for caracter especial
while(regexEspecialCharacters.test(letra)){
  letra = prompt("Digite APENAS uma letra:");
}
//passando variável para minúscula 
letra = letra.toLowerCase();

//checando vogais
if(regexVogal.test(letra)){
   document.write(letra + " é uma vogal");
}else{
  document.write(letra + " é uma consoante!");
}
```